# Deselecting item in listBox wont adjust the count of items selected

Tags: c#

Im currently trying to make a form that calculates a subtotal based on the amount of items that are selected in a listBox. When I delselect an item the subtotal reverts back to normal but when I select another item in the list I find the count wasnt updated along with the deselection. I feel like this has to do with the extras++ portion but I dont know how to fix it.

```
for (int counter = 0; counter < extrasListBox.Items.Count; counter++)
        {
            if (extrasListBox.GetSelected(counter))
            {
                extras++;

                extraCost = extras * EXTRA;

                subtotal += extras;
            }
            else if ()
            {
                extras--;
            }
        }
```

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know where you written this code, but if you didn't write this in SelectedIndexChanged ListBox Event you should do, or try to write else instead of else if

```
private void extrasListBox_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
   for (int counter = 0; counter < extrasListBox.Items.Count; counter++)
    {
        if (extrasListBox.GetSelected(counter))
        {
            extras++;

            extraCost = extras * EXTRA;

            subtotal += extras;
        }
        else if ()
        {
            extras--;
        }
    }
}
```